# PDF files won't publish to site in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdf, publish

When working on a website in Visual Studios and adding PDF files, they won't Publish to the site via the "Publish" command. Does this have something to do with the filetype?

Thanks in Advance,
CJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to change the build action to Content in the file's properties.

It's probably set to None at the moment, which will mean it isn't copied up in the publish process.

Comment: That was it! I set it to content and it uploaded via "Publish" Thank you!